# Unexpected error thrown in PostgreSQL's function and not catched

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to make a list of users who are modified and then at the end of transaction I would like to process the list. Here's how I'm trying to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE "user"(
    user_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_5 PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE FUNCTION enlist_user ()
        RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS $$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        rec := NEW;
    ELSE
        rec := OLD;
    END IF;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_list (
        user_id bigint NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT user_queue_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
    );

    INSERT INTO user_list
    VALUES (rec.user_id);

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Unable to add %', rec.user_id;

    RETURN rec;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER user_modified
        AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
        ON "user"
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE enlist_user();

INSERT INTO "user" VALUES (default, 'qwe');
```

But running the above code results in follow error:

```
ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function enlist_user()
```

What's going on? Why `RETURN rec` did not work?

Comment: Your `return rec` is inside the `exception` block (which is hidden by your "wrong" indention). If no exception is thrown that line is never reached.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you please correct it? How should I terminate the exception's block?

Comment: The exception block is terminated with the `end` that you already have. But if no exception is raised, it won't be executed. Logically the keyword `exception` is on the same level as your `begin` - the indention you have is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indention is misleading. The `exception` part belongs logically on the same level as the first `begin`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION enlist_user ()
        RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS $$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    ...

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Unable to add %', rec.user_id;

  RETURN rec; -- << only reached if an exception is thrown.
END;
$$;
```

So the `RETURN` is part of the exception block and thus only reached *if* an exception occurs. What you actually want is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION enlist_user ()
        RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    ...

  RETURN rec; -- normal flow of the function

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Unable to add %', rec.user_id;

END;
$$;
```

You also shouldn't just do a `raise notice` which means that the original exception won't be shown to the end user. The caller also will not have any clue that an exception happened. It's better if you re-raise the exception that you handled:

```
  .... 
  RETURN rec; -- normal flow of the function

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Unable to add %', rec.user_id;
  RAISE; -- signal this error to the caller
END;
$$;
```